# Yarn 2.0: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: yarnpkg, yarn-v2

Attempting to migrate to yarn 2.0 and run into a problem with private npm packages resulting in

```
YN0001: │ GotError: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Got around this in yarn 1.x with the `strict-ssl: false` config setting. Is there a way of doing something similar in the new `.yarnrc.yml`? Couldn't find anything related in the [docs](https://next.yarnpkg.com/configuration/yarnrc).

My .yarnrc.yml:

```
yarnPath: .yarn/releases/yarn-sources.js
npmScopes:
  companyName:
    npmRegistryServer: "https://www.myget.org/F/companyName/npm"
```

Comment: Have you solved the it for yarn 2?
I have found this maybe.
https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/issues/798
They suggests doing `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 yarn ...`

Comment: enableStrictSsl: false to disable cert errors.